# Difference of "Azure Fuction Isolated" and "Azure App Serive"

Tags: .net, azure

What's the difference of "Azure Fuction Isolated" and "Azure App Serive"? Is "Azure App service" always a better choice?

Comment: The main difference is vendor lock-in... and the inability to run things on-prem.

Comment: @Dai Thanks, I get your point. Publish an isolated function to local folder then run `exe` will get error.

Answer (score -1):

Azure Functions and Azure App Service are both serverless compute services offered by Microsoft Azure, but they serve slightly different purposes and have different characteristics. Within Azure Functions, there is a distinction between "Azure Functions Isolated" and "Azure App Service" that can be confusing, so let's clarify the differences between these two:

1. Azure Functions Isolated:

   - Azure Functions Isolated is a variation of Azure Functions that allows you to run your functions in a more controlled and isolated environment compared to the regular Azure Functions runtime.
   - It provides more customization options for the runtime and execution environment.
   - You can choose your own custom dependencies and runtime version, which can be useful for scenarios that require specific libraries, versions, or configurations.
   - It is typically used for scenarios where you need more control over the underlying infrastructure, and it's well-suited for applications with specific security or compliance requirements.
   - Azure Functions Isolated is often used when you need to run Functions on Kubernetes using Azure Functions on Kubernetes (KEDA) or in other specialized scenarios.
2. Azure App Service:

   - Azure App Service is a platform-as-a-service (PaaS) offering in Azure that is designed for hosting web applications, APIs, and mobile backends.
   - It abstracts away most of the infrastructure management tasks and provides a fully managed platform for web applications, including features like automatic scaling, load balancing, and easy deployment.
   - While you can run background tasks or scheduled jobs using Azure Functions within an Azure App Service, the primary focus of App Service is hosting web applications.
   - Azure App Service provides different hosting plans, including shared, dedicated, and premium plans, allowing you to choose the right level of resources and scalability for your application.

In summary, Azure Functions Isolated is a specific variant of Azure Functions that offers more control and customization over the runtime environment, often used for specialized and demanding scenarios. Azure App Service, on the other hand, is primarily designed for hosting web applications and provides a fully managed PaaS environment. The choice between the two depends on the specific requirements and use case of your application.

Comment: Please declare if you wrote this answer yourself, or if you used a service like ChatGPT to generate it for you.

Comment: _"It provides more customization options for the runtime and execution environment."_ - this is not a feature of Azure Functions compared to App Services.. it's from a comparison of Isolated vs non-Isolated Azure Functions.